# Alphabetically sorting strings

Tags: c++, string, sorting

I need to make program that sorts strings in alphabet order. How can I do that?

Comment: First, you get all the strings. Are you going to get it from input or file? Afterwards, you need to see if you can use std::string or if you need to use char array. Moreover, check if you are allowed to use std::sort or if you have to implement the sort by yourself. Since you are on it, check if you need to store the string in a array or if you can use std::vector for example.

Comment: I should input strings from user in a array and I don't have any limitations. It only needs to program run correctly.

Comment: First write a program that opens a file successfully.  Make sure it works.  Then add code to read a line from the file in a loop.  Make sure it works.  Then add code to store each line read in an array, make sure it works.  Etc.. Have you done any of these preliminary steps?

Comment: @ĐorđeMilanović You need to decide what sorting method to use.:) The simplest methods are bubble sort, selection sort, insertion sort. But they are not efficient. You can try to write the quick sort or some other method.

Comment: I have stored all strings in one array, and all with it works, I only need somehow to sort them and print after (that I know).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Excuse me because I'm now in C++ and i don't know any of your expressions (selection sort, bubble sort and insertion sort). I only want if you can give me some function that sort array. Please

Comment: @ĐorđeMilanović There is already such a function in C++. It is named std::sort and it is declared in header <algorithm>

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks for that Vlad. I have found that command on internet. Привет от Сербии. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Strings are compared by their letters in order. Let's take a moment to remember that strings, at the end of the day, are characters arrays, and let's remember too that characters have a numerical value by themselves, ranging from lowercase 'a' to uppercase 'Z', 'a' being the lowest value in the alphabet and uppercase Z being the highest. So, behind the curtains, when comparing two strings with comparing operators, you are putting against each other two numerical values, if they happen to be the same, then the comparison is taken to the next letter in their string. For example, "dog" would be put first than "doll" if you are sorting lowest to highest.

```
"dog" < "doll" //This will return true
```

Now, for the sorting, I would recommend you to look up for **sorting methods** in **data structures**, or try to come up with one yourself knowing how strings compare.

Comment: Can I sort them as if(a[i] < a[i+1]) condition?

Comment: If that's an array of strings, yeah.

Comment: Read Crazy Eddie's answer's comments, he gives some more insight in this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::sort` (2nd version) and write a comparison function that compares characters alphabetically rather than lexicographically.  If this has to deal with i18n/l10n then this function might be more difficult to write.

Comment: What's the difference between lexicographical order and alphabetical order on strings?

Comment: @moooeeeep - lexicographical compares based on the underlying encoding--generally something based on ASCII in English.  This means that 'z' comes before 'A'...and all the numbers in fact.  Alphabetically would generally put numbers first, then 'a', then 'A', then 'b', etc...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please do not ask people to do your homework here on SO. However, since you've already got most of the program down, I'll give you a few tips:

Firstly you need to read in the strings, and store them in some way:

- Strings (Decent method)
- Arrays (Probably should avoid these)
- Vectors (Much better alternative to arrays)

Now you can either use the built-in function std::sort (but I guess you're not allowed to use it as this is homework) or write a sort function on your own.

Think about how to search a string/array/vector for a specific letter in the alphabet (Googling 'c++ search string' would give you a few methods) and consider the effects of uppercase, lowercase and punctuation.

The main problem is that there's no way for a computer to see if a letter comes 'before' another - see if you can find a way to convert from a character to a number (hint: use casting in conjunction with an ASCII table).

That's all the info I'm gonna give, good luck!

EDIT: A few words on sorting methods

There are a few main sorting methods:

- Bubblesort - Go through the string in order, swapping letters that
  are in the wrong order. Repeat this over and over until the string is
  sorted
- Insertion sort - For each letter, put it in a new array/string/vector in the correct place
- Quicksort - Split the string in two, compare the halves, swap portions and repeat